# Installing SSH in Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: ssh

Hello every one I tried to install SSH in my Ubuntu 14.04LTS which is in vmware but most of the time i get the following error message please what could be wrong?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ssh : Depends: openssh-server (>= 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: For a start you forgot to include the command you ran.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install -f` this should help solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install openssh-client # client for secure access to remote machines  
sudo apt-get install aptitude  
sudo aptitude install ssh
```

Optional commands:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server # server for secure access from remote machines
sudo apt-get install hotssh # GUI front-end for ssh
```